# How to prevent updating LockoutEndDateUtc

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

In the web application, whenever creating a new user, set IsActive to true and IsLockoutEnabled to false, however, currently customers report issues when they use the web application, that is sometimes, after serveral access failures, the LockoutEndDateUtc is set and the customer cannot login any longer.

How to prevent updating LockoutEndDateUtc for ever?

====================================================
below change not work, in the constructor of UserManager:

```
// disalbe lockout
this.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = false;
this.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 100000;
```

Answer (score 1):

For a user to be not locked out the `LockoutEnabled` must be false and `LockoutEndDateUtc` must be before the current date. To disable Locking out globally you must set `UserLockoutEnabledByDefault` to false on the `UserManager`

```
public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
{
    var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));

    // Disable lock outs
    manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = false;
    manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 0; 
    manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = 0;

    //....
}
```

Comment: Thank, Alper, actually I want to disable lockout, and following your suggestion, I add the code snippet in the constructor of UserManager (see update), still after several login failures, the LockoutEndDateUtc is still updated.

Comment: you can inject UserManager like here https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/e0ded5d8702f389aa1f5947d3446f16aec845287/src/Abp.Zero/Authorization/AbpLoginManager.cs#L33 and set the UserLockoutEnabledByDefault  = false on that instance.

Comment: still not work, the AccessFailedCount is increased after failure, and LockoutEndDateUtc updated.

Comment: I don't think it's related to ABP. Maybe ask on Microsoft's Identity repository